# What is the complexity class of performing a perfect disassembly of binary code?

Tags: complexity-theory

I have heard that the complexity class of performing a perfect disassembly of binary is undecidable. Is this correct? Are there any proofs of this?

Comment: There is no single format called "assembly" or "binary." It is entirely dependent on the instruction set and disassembly syntax.

Comment: I've heard that performing a perfect disassembly reduces to the halting problem somehow. I don't think it depends on the machine-code syntax. It sounded like a universal problem with all Turing-complete languages.

Comment: Sometimes data is embedded in code for constants and jump tables and things. If you phrased/contrived your notion of disassembly to handle this in just the right way, and had the right architecture, it's easy enough to construct a situation where one would have to decide if the data was entered or not to determine if it should be rendered as code. In practice heuristics are used and they're 99% accurate but sometimes fail.

Comment: The question will be very hard to answer until you define your problem formally.

Comment: And once you defined the problem precisely enough that’s most of the work done.